# Массив данных и целевая функция

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, функции, математика

Есть массив данных с условными объектами. У каждого объекта есть набор признаков (со значениями) и значение 
целевой функции.

Цель: найти сцепку признаков, которые оказывают наибольшее влияние на 
целевую функцию, максимизируя ее. *Определить долю влияния каждого 
признака  на целевую функцию (например, признак 1 сильнее признака 2 в 
1.5 раза и т.д.). В идеале получить аналитическую формулу для целевой 
функции через признаки.
Например:
Объект1 - 1, 334, 1,41, 9485123, -, 0, магазин, 984564 (это целевая функция).
Объект2 - 0, 334, 0, 599693, 1, -, кафе, 899411 (целевая).
и т.д.

Какие алгоритмы можно к этой задаче применить? и где мне вообще копать. С алгоритмами особо не дружу, буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: _Цель: найти сцепку признаков, которые оказывают наибольшее влияние на целевую функцию, максимизируя ее._ Это называется "корреляционный анализ".

Comment: Спасибо, теперь будет проще разобраться)